# how to increment a varchar with leading zeroes in sql

Tags: sql

i have a varchar in the format '@0001' and i need to increment the value by 1 so that the result is @0002.this goes on till @9999.

Pls suggest

Comment: Edit your question and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: You should change your data model. If the number has a meaning to you (you want to do a calculation), why don't you store it as a number (i.e. number 1 instead of string '@0001')?

Comment: what does @9999 become?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Don't. Rolling your own auto-increment is bound to fail. Use the buit in mechanism and format the output of queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column =
    concat('@', lpad(to_number(substr(my_column, 2, 4)) + 1, 4, '0000'));
```

Same idea but with different functions for another database.

Comment: how will this handle the @sign?

Comment: Oops...yeah the @sign... Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For SQl Server this will work, however note that in the case of the value @9999 it woudl return @0000. If you want to move tha to five characters it gets more complicated. It is also more complicated if you have some data points that have less than 4 characters after the @ sign.

```
create table #temp (id varchar(50))
insert into #temp (id) values ('@0001'), ('@0991'), ('@9999')

select id, '@'+right('0000' +cast(cast (Right(id, 4) as Int) + 1 as varchar(50)), 4) from #temp
```

The potential complexity of this and the ability to handle data  issues mean that this is something you would not want to do to a large set of data and something that would have to be adjusted or made much more complex to handle values incrementing over four characters or if teh first character could be different. Personally, I would find it preferable to correctly store the data in its component pieces if you need to do this as more than a one_tiem conversion.